# Is HLS (HTTP) faster than UDP for streaming?

Tags: network-protocols

Is HLS (HTTP) faster than UDP for streaming?

HLS definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming#Clients

UDP definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

HTTP definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: That rather depends on the protocol you implement on top of UDP. Theoretically it certainly can be. Did you have any particular implementation in mind?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with faster? Lower latency, lower jitter, more bandwidth, ...?

Comment: Oh, and it is infinitely more efficient on any network which blocks most anything but the HTTP protocol. Which I imagine is the problem HLS was designed to circumvent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not faster.  The point of HLS is that it dynamically adapts to the available network bandwidth.  Automatically switching to a lower quality video stream when the download speed is reduced.  You get to keep watching the movie without the annoying spinner.

HLS is a version of the generic [Adaptive bitrate streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming) protocol.  There are several competing implementations, they all work the same way but have incompatible details:

- HLS is Apple's HTTP Live Streaming protocol
- HDS is Adobe's HTTP Dynamic Streaming
- Microsoft's version is Microsoft Smooth Streaming
- DASH is an industry standard, Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP.  The standard to replace them all, thus adding a 4th standard.

The principle behind it is very simple.  The content provider generates a handful of different encodings of the source material with different quality settings.  Split up into segments, each several seconds worth of video.  And a manifest that describes these streams and segments, a simple XML file.

The client video player first downloads the manifest and starts downloading the first segment of the lowest quality encoding.  Playback starts almost immediately.  The player keeps downloading segments one by one and monitors how quickly it can get them.  If throughput is good then it *switches* to a higher quality encoding.  And conversely, when the player is in danger of running behind then it switches to a lower quality.  Thus dynamically adapting to changing network load.

Comment: Why not just use UDP w/ a TCP "heartbeat" ?

Comment: These kind of "what-if" questions are not very useful.  Surely they picked this scheme because it was so easy and cheap to implement.  Just copy the everything to a CDN and it's done, no dedicated servers required.

Comment: @paul: RTP has some kind of TCP heartbeat and synchro called RTCP - see the RFCs for details.

Comment: TCP is faster than UDP over internet for video streaming enabling HD playback, hence HLS is a lot faster than RTSP over UDP. Adaptive Bitrate Streaming is not a protocol, it's a general technique and it's not limited to HTTP streaming as it can be done over RTMP as well. Apple was first to do segmented, adaptive HTTP streaming for both Live and VoD (HLS) using MPEG-2 chunks. Newer implementations like SmoothStreaming or HDS use fragmented MP4, fMP4 which is real standard for clunking media while chunking MPEG-2 is not standardized.It requires specialized servers for anything else than home fun

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance RTP/UDP streaming is far better but there is no guarantee that it will get transported through the internet via routers/nat boxes, proxies, etc.

HLS on the other hand is built on top of HTTP which is kind of ubiquitous. The chance of receiving video streams over HTTP is higher than RTSP/RTP, RTMP and so on.

In terms of performance - HLS has overheads due to the IP/TCP/HTTP/HLS stacking. Those overheads were in my tests somewhere between 12-20%.

So, if you can control the network end-to-end I suggest using RTP/UDP. Otherwise HLS is a safer choice.

Comment: Why not just use TCP then?

Comment: @paul: because as someone previously said retransmission may hinder your streaming. Moreover, it doesn't deal very well with the frames inside the stream. It is better to drop a frame than retrasmit a broken one several times. Codecs can deal with lost frames, but retransmissions may introduce massive jitter. Using simple TCP on random ports is also not guaranteed to be transported over internet or in some restricted networks.